# The best way to implement custom variables with Google Analytics

Tags: 7, google-analytics

I need to use [Google Analytics custom variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables) , but I want to give a different variable value depending of the urls.

I'm checking the G.A module, but I don't see how to define the variables to say when to use one token or other depending of the url.

The only way I see is build a token that checks the url and gives me back the value.

I'm thinking in something more close to [Paths Breadcrumbs](https://drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs) where you can define context and choose a token/value depending of the context.

Answer (score 2):

"Custom variables" are now [Custom dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets).

The [Google Analytics](https://drupal.org/project/google_analytics) module supports custom dimensions and metrics.

See the module's README.txt:

> One example for custom dimensions tracking is the "User roles" tracking.
>
> 1. In the Google Analytics Management Interface you need to setup Dimension #1    with name e.g. "User roles". This step is required. Do
>      not miss it, please.
> 2. Enter the below configuration data into the custom dimensions settings form    under admin/config/system/googleanalytics. You can
>      also choose another index,    but keep it always in sync with the
>      index used in step #1.
>
>    Index: 1    Value: [current-user:role-names]